# Anyone found a way to access HP ILO via XML API from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, ilo

Is there a way to use HP's XML API for ILO with PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod and/or Invoke-WebRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on a piece of software that does exactly that.  If I recall, the method is simply to `POST` the XML document you generate according to the documentation, and parse the reply.  Powershell allows you to construct and send these documents with the `xml` type, and parse the reply using an object model.

In other words, yes, of course you can do that.  Just fetch the WSDL, write some code that constructs your documents, and transcieve them with the server using the HTTP cmdlets you've identified.

Comment: I tried sending a text document test.xml but that didn't seem to do much.

Comment: In my experience it tends to ignore invalid stuff or things it otherwise doesn't like.  There is a lot of trial and error in the process.